# length of duration from url video on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed wordpress on my server and whenever I am creating a post , I am copying URL embed "`<iframe src="http://video.com12432" frameborder="0" width="560" height="340" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>`" to content post,add a Feature Image for thumbnail post and save the post.

My question is, how can I put video duration over my thumbnail already created?
Is any php function so I can add to wordpress theme?
Instead of "3 days ago" to have Duration 30:00  [click here for printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJAOU.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a function that gets video duration from file path: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_read_video_metadata/